# ADD failed: file not found in build context or excluded by .dockerignore:

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, docker-image, rancher-desktop

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:8
EXPOSE 8080
ADD target/springboot-example.jar springboot-example.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/springboot-example.jar"]
```

While running `docker build`, I see this error:

> Step 3/4 : ADD target/springboot-example.jar springboot-example.jar
> ADD failed: file not found in build context or excluded by .dockerignore: stat target/springboot-example.jar: file does not exist

Comment: Are you sure you the file `target/springboot-example.jar` exists?
It might have a different name, depending on how have configured the jar name generation E.g if you have the version built into the name before the `.jar`, you can use a wildcard: `ADD target/springboot-example*.jar springboot-example.jar`

Comment: Have you tried to specify a WORKDIR?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the target file isn't match with pom.xml file.

Your target `springboot-example` is the (`<artifactId>`+`<version>`**.jar**) in pom.xml. I think `springboot-example` you declared in the dockerfile is doesn't match with **artifactId** and **version** tag in the pom.xml file. Just make sure your project with follow this step:

### Step-1

go to the pom.xml file and make sure your `<grupId>` and `<artifactId>` its same with your Dockerfile target
[image]

### Step-2

Setting the Dockerfile, for my project it will be like this:

```
FROM openjdk:17
ADD target/intermnc-0.0.1.jar intermnc-0.0.1.jar
EXPOSE 8081
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "-c", "java ${JAVA_OPTS} -jar intermnc-0.0.1.jar"]
```

Its SOLVED in my case, good luck dude!

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by specifying relative path instead of absolute path.

My DockerFile and all other files were at "/root/files" directory and I was inside "/root/files" directory.

Earlier I had below statement in Dockerfile,

```
ADD --chown=abcuser:abc /root/files/patches.bom /opt/sbj/patches/patches.bom
```

which I changed to,

```
ADD --chown=abcuser:abc ./patches.bom /opt/sbj/patches/patches.bom
```

This worked.